# How to change Html of a particular cell in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

In my jqGrid implementation, we have a subgrid with a dropdown and we want to change the icon in a cell on change of that dropdown. I have used the `Formatter` to generate the icons shown in the picture below. But now I want to add/remove the icon images from the cell. Is this possible to do? I'd greatly appreciate any help/ideas for that? We are using the jqGrid for ASP .NET in this project.

[image]

```
function formatActionGridIcons(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    if (cellValue.indexOf("_") == -1) return '';

    var arr = cellValue.split('_');

    var icon1 = arr[0];
    var icon2 = arr[1];
    var icon3 = arr[2];

    //if (icon1 == "R")
    var cellHtml = getIconHtml(icon1) + getIconHtml(icon2) + getIconHtml(icon3); 
    return cellHtml;

}
function getIconHtml(icon) {
    if (icon == null || icon == "") return "";
    var result = GetIconPath(icon);
    if (typeof (result) === "undefined" || result == "")
        return "";
    else
         return "<img src='" + GetIconPath(icon) + "' width='18px' height='18px' />";
}
function unformatActionGridIcons(cellValue, options, cellObject) {
    return $(cellObject.html()).attr("originalValue");
}
```

Comment: You can use _custom formatter_ for it. If you could post the colmodel of this formatter, that would be better to post some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Jai, this is done using custom formatters. I can see the colModel in the source generated. Remember this is the commercial version of jqGrid for ASP .NET so we define the columns as ASP .NET control tags. But I have posted the code for the custom formatter here.

Comment: The code of `getIconHtml` looks strange because it return *always* the empty string `""` (see both if and else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setCell` to modify the cell with icons. It calls internally the formatter of the cell to generate HTML fragment which will be set in the grid. So you need just use the same format of data `setCell` for its 3-d parameter like you use in the input of the grid.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks. A side question though. Is it possible to extract the original value from a column which has Custom Formatter on? I was using `return $(cellObject.html()).attr("originalValue");` in my `UnFormat` method but was getting the html in `getCell` method

Comment: @Imran: You are welcome! There are many ways to implement the requirement. I was wonder that you used `.attr("originalValue")` in the unformatter. I supposed that you set the attribute inside of `cellattr` which you don't posted. Such way could be one possible implementation. Another way will work if you use `datatype: "local"` or if you use `loadonce: true`. The `option` parameter of unformatter contains `rowId` and `colModel``property. So you can use `var rowdata = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", options.rowId);` to get rowdata and `rowdata[option.colModel.name]` to get the column value.